# C++Builder 5 Set TDBChart Series Visible

Tags: c++builder, teechart

Does anyone know how you can configure the visibility of a TeeChart Series programmatically in C++? I can't seem to find the right proprety using the auto completion.

I basically want to set Series1 visible at certain times and Series2 invisible, and the other way round following different conditions.

What I basically want is something to this effect :

```
Series1->Visible = false;
Series2->Visible = true;
```

except that **this doesn't work**.

If anyone could help, that would be greatly appreciated.

Chris

Comment: Which TeeChart version are you using? The one included with C++ Builder 5? Or a registered version from Steema Software? I that's the case, please specify which version is it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it's the one included with Builder 5 - TeeChart Pro 4.02 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to my own question. The property is "**Active**" - don't know why I didn't think of it before.

*C++ :*

```
Series1->Active = False;
Series2->Active = True;
```

EDIT : Beware, even if you change the title of your series, the "real" name to use in this code will probably still be Series1/2/... . This is because every Series you create (by right clicking on the TDBChart->Chart->Series->Add) creates a TBarSerie which seemingly can only be accessed from the Object inspector. The title you give it doesn't affect its real name.

Thanks for your comment, Narcis Calvet.